# VS2012 sol'n with CUDA 5 ==> VS2010 with CUDA 5.5

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, cuda

I received a "VS2012 + CUDA 5.0" solution, and would like use it in my "VS2010 + CUDA 5.5" environment.
I was able to get VS2010 open the solution but the compiles are failing:
"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Platforms\x64\Microsoft.Cpp.x64.Targets(514,5): error MSB8008: Specified platform toolset (v110) is not installed or invalid"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve this particular problem I would try to navigate to:

1. open project properties,
2. navigate to configuration properties -> general -> platform toolset,
3. open the dropdown and choose v100 (VS2010 toolset) instead of v110 (VS2012).

Having said that, you may encounter various other problems once you are past this issue, e.g. some c++11 feature used in the solution which is not supported in VS2010 or similar. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx#featurelist) for more details.